# Youtrack problem with Issues Getter Count endpoint

Tags: youtrack-api

I have this request issues count:

```json
{

"folder": {

"$type":"Project",

"id":"0-103"

},

"query":"from:me project:{CSDEV} 1006654684352 usuario123",

"unresolvedOnly":false

}
```

but the response in count field, most of the time it is -1, eventually it is the correct value.... this is a bug? exists solution?